# Is there a way not allow direct access to cgi-bin but only allow local php access

Tags: php, apache, cgi-bin

Right now a user can directly execute something in the cgi-bin directory by using a url 
http:\someserver\cgi-bin\mycommand

I don't want to allow the user to do that but allow a php script to execute using the code below.

**Is this possible?**
Thanks in advance

```
define ("CGI_CMD_URL_URL",          "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/cgi-bin/mycommand");

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array
(
   'http' => array
   (
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n',
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $data,
   ),
);

// create context
$context = stream_context_create($options);

// open the stream to get the output from CGI_CMD_URL_URL
$uploadstream = @fopen(CGI_CMD_URL_URL, 'rb', false, $context);
if (!$uploadstream)
{
    $_SESSION[ADDITIONAL_MSG] = $php_errormsg;
    report_error(SOME_ERROR);
}

// read the result
$result = stream_get_contents($uploadstream);

// close the stream
fclose($uploadstream);

// return data
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with .htaccess in case of Apache Webserver. You must deny all and allow your host only.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html

Respect that any self-calling method on your webserver is a try that impacts your server-performance and reduce the possible max client calls on that engine. In my point of view such tasks are worst practice ( in a lot of cases ).